# Third party datasource implementation for BigQuery data transfer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-transfer, connector

I want to create a custom datasource for Marketo for google bigquery data transfer. I don't see any specific document to integrate a third party datasource. Kindly provide the steps to integrate a third party datasource.

Comment: See this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/ if you have any specific question please update your original text

Answer (score 0):

A Marketo data transfer for google BigQuery is already available, you can find it in the [market place](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/fivetran-bq-dts/marketo).

Here is the documentation on how to use a [third party data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/third-party-transfer).

Answer (score 0):

As long there ODBC or SQL golang driver for Marketo you can also use [DbSync](https://github.com/viant/dbsync/)
to get real-time table synchronization/replication.